# How to use multiple files in a php webpage

Tags: php

I am creating a webpage with PHP/MySQL, and each page is in its own .php file.

How should I organize the addressbar, when changing the viewing page?

I have thought of two different ways to solve this:

```
1) www.mywebpage.com/?page=REFERENCES+pageid=GUID_TO_USE_FOR_DB_LOOKUP

2) www.mywebpage.com/references.php?GUID_TO_USE_FOR_DB_LOOKUP
```

Which should I choose? Are there other ways to do this?

Edit: When the user clicks a link to another page, I want to redirect the user to the corresponding .php file. The question is how to show this in the addressbar in the web browser.

With the GUID_TO_USE_FOR_DB_LOOKUP, I want to pass parameter to the .php file

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by address bar? What does the value GUID_TO_USE_FOR_DB_LOOKUP mean? Are you looking for a template engine?

Comment: If I were you, I'd go for 2). It's more clear and easily organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it:

`www.mywebpage.com/references/GUID.html`

You can use mod_rewrite to use URLs like this and have them mapped to "references.php?GUID=xyz" internally.

However, all solutions are fine and will work the same way (display the page), the advantage of the above is just that the URL is more "readable" as well as better for search engine optimization as the URL-"path" is parsed by search engines (other than using parameters).

Search for "mod_rewrite SEO" to find out more about this topic, e.g.:
http://www.htmlist.com/how-to/a-simplemod_rewrite-tutorial/

A couple of questions to ask:
Why do you care about the URL? Should it be human readable? Do you care about SEO? Do you like to use a "framework" with a single point of entry (which could work like your first example)? Do you want to "hide" your actual filenames from your users? etc. etc.

Comment: I would like the URL to be easier to read, and also "hide" filenames from the user.

Comment: @eflles this method would hide the filenames. in fact he is suggesting making it look like a fake file `GUID.html` exists when in reality you are re-routing the request from `www.mywebpage.com/references/SomeGuid.html` to `www.mywebpage.com/references.php?GUID=SomeGuid`. The visitor would the first url and the server would process the request as the second. Google (or search SO) "php and mod_rewrite" for more information.

Comment: @eflles than the mod_rewrite-solution is for you :)